# Android studio, debugging an infinite loop

Tags: android

I am trying to debug an infinite loop in my program in android studio. I have a lot of breakpoints set up but every time I try to run it, it gets to a point where it just says "The application is running" and stalls out until the phone runs out of memory. What tool in Android studio is there to see the flow of the program? Specifically what methods are being called and which one is being called ad infinitum.

Comment: run in debug, then press the pause button. it will pause all threads, allowing you to see where is the loop

Answer (score 1):

To see your code execution stopped on breakpoint, you need to run it in debug mode <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Normal run (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) is not affected by breakpoints.

See this article: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html